# Form is flushed instead of just returning the error in EasyAdmin (Symfony)

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I have an entity User
In a CrudController for the crud "edit",
I submit a form. Then in several FormEvents (SUBMIT and POST_SET_DATA) I check if there is errors. I add errors in the form with, for example,
$form->get('name')->addError(new FormError...)
And I return false.

I would like to stop the form and just return the errors. I can see the errors in the form but the data are flushed.
Why it don't cancel the form if there is errors ?

For example :

```
$formBuilder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {

    $form = $event->getForm();
    /** @var User $thisUser */
    $thisUser = $event->getData();
    $validatorMap = $this->validationService->checkInfiniteLoopValidation($thisUser);
    if ($validatorMap === null) {
        $form->get('validators')->addError(new FormError('Impossible d\'ajouter ce valideur pour ' . $thisUser->getName() . '. Il doit surement être déjà validé par un des valideurs'));
        return false;
    }
});`
```

`
I would like to know if there is a possibility to prevent the form to submit the data in the database while there is errors in the form.

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have a PRE_SUBMIT event? if yes try to add error here

Comment: Thank you for your answer but It also does not work. I realy dont know what to do... For the front i can just do $form->isValid() to stop the data flushed... but I don't know with easyAdmin...